# Query OR Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a problem with this query, whis is wrong?
But I don't have any errors:

```
public function find($name, $cod)
    {
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $select->from('table', 'id');
        $select->where("nome LIKE '%.$name.%' OR  codiceArticolo '%.$cod.%'");

        $rows = $select->query()->fetchAll();
        return $rows[0];
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the `.` in this bit? `'%.$name.%'` - it seems to be changing your search criteria?

Comment: Try `echo $select;` and run the query directly and check for any errors

Comment: "I have a problem" is to broad, nevertheless I think you're missing the operator `LIKE` between `codiceArticolo` and `'%.$cod.%'` and you're misusing the concatenation operator `.`, try `$select->where("nome LIKE '%{$name}%' OR  codiceArticolo LIKE '%{$cod}%'");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are changing your search by using the string concat full stops in your code:

I believe either of the two following will solve the issue:

```
public function find($name, $cod)
{
    $select = $this->getSelect();
    $select->from('table', 'id');
    $select->where("nome LIKE '%".$name."%' OR  codiceArticolo '%".$cod."%'");

    $rows = $select->query()->fetchAll();
    return $rows[0];
}
```

or

```
public function find($name, $cod)
{
    $select = $this->getSelect();
    $select->from('table', 'id');
    $select->where("nome LIKE '%$name%' OR  codiceArticolo '%$cod%'");

    $rows = $select->query()->fetchAll();
    return $rows[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong here:

```
$select->where("nome LIKE '%.$name.%' OR  codiceArticolo '%.$cod.%'");
                            ^     ^
```

Try this:

```
$select->where("nome LIKE '%".$name."%' OR  codiceArticolo '%.$cod.%'");
```

or

```
$select->where("nome LIKE '%$name%' OR  codiceArticolo '%.$cod.%'");
```